# Indexed_search only the news detail

Tags: typo3-9.x

I'm setup a TYPO3 v9.5 website with the Indexed_search ext.

When I search a word using the seachbox on the FE it show all results : home page, categories pages, and news pages.

there is a way to index/search only the newsitems detail page ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

In my opinion the simplest (without setting up crawler configurations) would be to limit indexing to only this page.

See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/master/en-us/Configuration/General/Index.html

On your root page you would set `page.config.index_enable = 0` in TypoScript setup and on your news detail page `page.config.index_enable = 1`. Then clear and rebuild the index.

Another possibility for smaller sites is to filter the shown results in your Fluid template. I would not really suggest that but it works, too.

Comment: using `page.config.index_enable = 0` its works, but also the page "News Detail" that contain news is displayed in the search results too. we should show only News items on it and not the page itself !

Comment: Then I would try my 2nd suggestion. Just filter them in the Fluid template with some <f:if... >